# Children alignment with their parent

Tags: alignment, forest

I've been looking for some hours examples for this unfortunately I can't find one that I can use, sorry for the inconvenience... I would like to have vertical alignment between the parent `$v_1$` and the second child `$v_4$` in the following example, since it is slightly to the right side, but the question is more general for several children and their parent, I would like to have it with some "symmetry", here is my example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, forest, tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
      for tree={anchor=center},
        [$v_1$
            [$v_2$
                [$v_3$[\scriptsize $3$, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm]]
                [$v_4$[\scriptsize $2$, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm]]
                [$v_6$[\scriptsize $2$, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm]]
            ]
            [$v_4$
                [$v_2$[\scriptsize $2$, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm]]
                [$v_5$[\scriptsize $1$, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm]]
                [$v_7$[\scriptsize $2$, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm]]
            ]
            [$v_5$
                [$v_3$[\scriptsize $3$, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm]]
                [$v_4$[\scriptsize $2$, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm]]
            ]
        ]
      \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `forest` package has the keys `calign` and `calign child` which you want to use on the root:

```
[v_1, calign=child, calign child=2 …]
```

If you have more than three children the `calign child` needs to changed or maybe evaluated automatically be `forest` (e.g. `calign child=int(n_children/2)+1` for an even number of children).

I've taken the liberty to use `math content` for your tree and put the options for the leaves into an automatic style that only gets applied when a node has no children.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    math content,
    where={n_children==0}{font=\scriptsize, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm}{}
  }
  [v_1, calign=child, calign child=2
      [v_2
          [v_3[3]]
          [v_4[2]]
          [v_6[2]]
      ]
      [v_4
          [v_2[2]]
          [v_5[1]]
          [v_7[2]]
      ]
      [v_5
          [v_3[3]]
          [v_4[2]]
      ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!, it works for what I want and the options suggested make easier the typing

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you can force `v_4` to be at the midpoint of `v_2` and `v_5` by using `before computing xy` and computing the average. The potentially unwanted consequence is that the subsequent children are not evenly spaced.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, forest, tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
      for tree={anchor=center},
        [$v_1$
            [$v_2$
                [$v_3$[\scriptsize $3$, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm]]
                [$v_4$[\scriptsize $2$, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm]]
                [$v_6$[\scriptsize $2$, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm]]
            ]
            [$v_4$, before computing xy={s/.average={s}{siblings}}
                [$v_2$[\scriptsize $2$, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm]]
                [$v_5$[\scriptsize $1$, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm]]
                [$v_7$[\scriptsize $2$, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm]]
            ]
            [$v_5$
                [$v_3$[\scriptsize $3$, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm]]
                [$v_4$[\scriptsize $2$, edge=densely dotted, l=.75cm]]
            ]
        ]
      \end{forest}
\end{document}
```